# Loading data to a table only when new data has been submitted to the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay, I am in a bit of a pickle, at the moment, I am using an ajax get, which appends data to the body table:

```
function buyupdate()
{
$.getJSON("<?php echo URL;?>/dashboard/openorders?market=<?php echo $coin;?>&type=buy", function(data){
    $("#buyingorders").find('tbody').empty();
    $.each(data.result, function(){
    $("#buyingorders").find('tbody').append("<tr onclick=\"set_price(2,"+this['price']+","+this['amount']+")\"><td>"+this['price']+"</td><td>"+this['amount']+"</td><td>"+this['cost']+"</td></tr>");
    })
});
}
```

This works, but it's not exactly great for the website's load, loading it every so many seconds, like so:

```
function done(){
setTimeout(function(){ buyupdate(); done(); },5000);
}
```

I don't know if this is possible, but is there any way I can only append data when a new row in the database has been added? Rather than keep loading the json page every so many seconds. The above function is getting data from a json which echoes all the rows in that specific table:

```
{"result":[{"price":"217.50","amount":"0.786236","cost":"178.13"}]}
```

Is this possible using jquery or ajax? In case this case is too braod: If so, links would be beneficial for myself and others who will read this question who aren't sure on how to.

Here's any example, this website's data is still updating, and only updating with new data:

[image: other website]

But mine has to check every 5 seconds for new data, which is putting a load on the server:

[image: mine]

Comment: Using ajax every n seconds is the only way unless you want to use websockets with something like iron.io or pusher (or your own persistent socket server) that would send notifications whenever the database changes.

Comment: Can you add a 'date modified' or 'timestamp' to the table? You will still need to use ajax but you could just append the new rows and not the whole lot.

Comment: No what you want to do is not possible using just jQuery or Ajax. You need a server side solution. Something like server-sent events (EventSource) or web sockets.